# Why does this new HVAC have open holes in the side?

Tags: hvac

My MIL has a Goodman HVAC installed and it's not cooling properly. I'm trying to understand what the outlets are for. One of them, is hooked into some PVC pipe which goes outside. The other outlet is uncovered and pushes out cool air.

I am attaching an image to show the two outlets in the unit. I am hoping someone can shed some light on what these do and if it may be related to the issues.

I Am wondering if it is installed properly or not.

[image]

Comment: Its not cooling properly. The house remains warm, the system is set to about 70F but the house remains over 75. the air coming out of the vents in the house  is not  cold

Comment: Please add any & all relevant and **detailed info** to the body of your question so that someone can provide an informed answer.

Comment: Charles although the home is warmer than the set point try setting it 5 degrees cooler and verify the outside unit is coming on.  How old is your unit?

Comment: What's "new" about this system? Just the furnace?

Comment: Call an HVAC professional.  You're having AC issues and you've shown us a picture of the furnace.  This is not even the thing that makes the cold.  You need to call someone that knows what they are doing.

Comment: If it's quite new, and if the AC is variable, one possible cause is a bad EEV in the expansion coil.  There is no way to fix this without specialist tools, so the option remains to call a pro.

Comment: Also, if you have a communicating thermostat with this system it may have information like the compressor suction and discharge temperatures and pressures.  If you wanted to start diagnosing this you could share that information, along with the furnace and AC make and model (and the thermostat make and model) with the system fully stopped (wait >1h) and then running at full cool.  That would start to get you some useful advice here, but still likely nothing you would be equipped to do anything about...

Answer (score 15):

[ **Edited** to reflect that this may or may not be outside vented and may or may not be dangerous. If you upvoted mainly because I warned of the dangers, now's your chance to remove it :) ]

That is a high efficiency heating system.  It uses a PVC pipe instead of a chimney for its exhaust.  There are two kinds. Some are "direct vent" that use another PVC pipe to ingest air from outside for combustion.    The other kind uses air from the room around the boiler for combustion (but still exhausts to the outside).

Hopefully yours is is designed to consume room air, as more thoroughly described in another answer, in which case the empty hole is where it gets its air.  If it's properly installed it will be in a room large enough to provide it plenty of air for combustion, or in a smaller room with one or more vents into larger spaces.  You should check the model and the manual to see if it is installed correctly and in a large enough space.

If yours is meant to be direct vented (consume outside air) it would have a second PVC pipe going outside.  Your manual will tell you.   Hopefully that's not the case but if it is, you should not use this for heating until it has been fixed.

**Either way** it's a good idea to install a CO detector near the unit.   As little at $15.  Some give you a reading so you know if it's non-zero even if not at danger levels.

All of this relates to heating.  I don't have an answer to the issue of not cooling.

Comment: one will be an inlet (which is fine to be left unconnected) the other will be the outlet which *must* be vented to the outside. You can differentiate them by opening the side pane and seeing which just opens up to the inside and which is properly connected to the heat exchanger. The first is the inlet the other is the outlet.

Comment: Most furnaces are not one type or the other - they can be installed as direct vented or the port can be left open to consume ambient air.  It's an installation option, typically, and not a specific design feature of the furnace - most are in fact designed to be installed *either way*.

Answer (score 10):

Yikes, hook that line back up!!! That line that hooks up to the combustion chamber and vents carbon monoxide out of the house!!!!

If your system is not cooling is it in cooling mode?
Are the batteries in the thermostat good?

If the system is a few years old it may have a small leak and be low on refrigerant!! But NEVER run the system with the vents disconnected!!!

I had a friend that died from carbon monoxide poisoning and you may be pumping it into your home.

Other things that can cause the system to not cool is dirty coils both inside and out. You can clean them and change the batteries

Comment: That's the fresh air intake, Ed.

Comment: @ monkeyzeus not if it is exhausting air when running.

Comment: OP states "pushes out cool air". The air should be fairly warm during a heating cycle. In modern furnaces the combustion chamber should be separated from the chamber with the blower but it's probably not leak proof so a small amount of cool air coming out of that port would be normal during a cooling cycle. I recently installed a Goodman furnace so there is a good chance they consistently locate their fresh air intake on that side.

Comment: @monkeyzeus the air is cold at startup and I have installed hundreds of furnaces and never had a intake blow air out.

Comment: @EdBeal All Goodmans of this vintage (post Amana/Daikin merger) are intake on the left (top, in this case), exhaust on the right (bottom, here).  The hookup looks correct.

Comment: Then either OP is mistaken or there is an actual problem with the furnace. At any rate that is a legal installation assuming the air supply is adequate. If your fresh air intake is exhausting combustion gases then venting it outside is a band-aide solution and only hides the actual problem.

Comment: It could be something simple like an air leak if the blower motor has rattled itself loose and is leaking high pressure air into the furnace body.  A broken seal otherwise between the low pressure and high pressure sides of the furnace would do this also.  It needs to be opened and inspected.  Nothing on the outside can tell us what's going on.

Comment: Closed combustion chambers have an intake that draw air in and an exhaust that blow air out it is that simple. Where these ports are depends on the model they are not all in the same place just as some furnaces are up flow and some are down flow. @monkeyzeus the op stated it was blowing air when he removed the vent I would say your assumption it is an intake is incorrect. The last Goodman I installed both intake and exhaust ports were vertical exit on the top of the unit. If j... is correct as I also suggested this is the exhaust and having the pipe removed is a major safety hazard.

Comment: @EdBeal The open pipe in OP's photo is NOT the exhaust.  I said exactly the opposite.  OP's unit is installed on its side, either in an attic or crawlspace.  The "top" ports you remember (assuming "the last Goodman" you installed was less than six years ago) are "side" ports in this orientation.  If it's in a vented space like an attic then there is absolutely no need to port the intake "outside" because it's already effectively "outside".

Comment: @EdBeal Also, keep in mind that OP is complaining about their AC not working - not the furnace.  When the AC is running the main blower fan is going and the condenser and compressor are working, but the combustion chamber is not, nor is the induction blower that drives the exhaust.  So if OP is having issues with air coming out of that port when the furnace is NOT running but the AC *is* running, it has to be something with the air sealing between the duct and the service chambers in the furnace.

Comment: @j... exhausting a combustion chamber inside the building envelope would violate code, I agree with the inducer not supposed to run in cooling but the unit is also not cooling , I did list several things like thermostat settings and batteries to also check.

Comment: @EdBeal You're stuck on that port being an exhaust - it's not.  An intake in the envelope is fine as long as there is makeup air, but it's a bit silly if you have the option to port it outside *unless* the furnace is already in a vented space, in which case the intake is not affecting the pressure inside the envelope - this was my point.  I wasn't talking about the exhaust at all.

Answer (score 5):

As strange as it sounds... this is valid in most areas.

Most people are used to water heaters and traditional HVAC furnaces, which need a double-wall metal flue to directly exhaust the hot combustion gases. What you have here is a [condensing furnace](https://www.thespruce.com/high-efficiency-condensing-furnace-1824740), which uses a secondary exchanger to increase efficiency by extracting the heat before sending the remaining exhaust up the PVC pipe (the air has been significantly cooled by that point) and out of the roof.

The open slot is your furnace air intake. I took the image below from [this installation PDF for a condensing furnace](https://www.questargas.com/ForEmployees/qgcOperationsTraining/Furnaces/Payne_PG9MAB_ASeries.pdf)

[image: Condensing furnace diagram]

While it might be preferred that the intake be further away from the HVAC unit, I have two in my attic and they both intake from the attic.

Why is cold air coming out of it? There's a few possibilities but I've noticed mine does the same thing. I suspect there is some part of the unit that moves outside the blower chamber. It passes over the parts that have been refrigerated (either by cooled ducting or the refrigerant pipes). The fact that air is coming out isn't necessarily a sign something is broken.

Comment: I don't think the furnace is causing the issues with the AC not working, but that aside, doesn't having the air intake inside the home require pulling fresh air into the space from outside?  I've always seen the air intakes outside below the exhaust on these types of units.  I assume your attic is not a conditioned space and is ventilated.

Comment: @JimmyJames Correct. I have a normal air return. This intake is strictly for the furnace burner. It does not mix with house air as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The uncovered outlet is a fresh air intake. It should not be pushing air out but should rather be sucking air in. Please verify that it is indeed sucking air in when heating; if it's actually pushing air out then there is a problem for sure.

If it's pushing air out during cooling and the burners are not activated then it could be working as designed.

The purpose of that hole is to provide enough fresh air for combustion of the furnace burners. Without that hole the system would be starved for air and won't heat properly; in fact it would trigger a system shutoff if you block off that hole. Most older homes are quite leaky so enough fresh air is available but well sealed homes typically require a pipe to be run outside so that fresh air can be guaranteed in the future event of properly insulating the home.

Running a pipe outside will not solve your cooling issue because it's only important for heating.

You should find and read through an installation manual for the furnace online. It's only about 30 pages and is quite informative.

As for the cooling issue it's possible that:

- The air conditioner which sits outside is undersized for the cooling needs of the home
- The coil which sits on the furnace is over/undersized in relation to the A/C outside
- The furnace/ac is misconfigured and might be on a conservative profile
- The system was not charged with enough freon
- The coils need to be cleaned
- The system has a freon leak

Comment: A intake will not be blowing air. Closed combustion furnaces have an intake and an exhaust. One draws or sucks fresh air in the other pushes warm air out. When the system first starts and the inducer motor turns on the air will be cold. There should be no airflow on the exhaust in cooling mode. If you are saying the furnace has a fresh air intake and this is the outlet that was vented ? That would be the first time I have ever seen that, the fresh air or makeup air intakes are on the intake side and vented with the standard airflow.

Comment: @EdBeal At no point does OP mention they "removed the vent". If this information was lost in a now-deleted comment then I apologize for missing that info. Without more information from OP we are only left with conjecture but I stand my ground that in a drafty home you do not need to run the intake outside. I think OP's assessment of air movement is up for debate though.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You don't *need* to, but negative pressure in a drafty house (or any house) is nasty and I can't imagine anyone wanting that for sake of a few feet of PVC.  The more likely scenario is that the furnace is in a vented space like an attic or crawlspace and so the intake drawing air from the vented space does not lead to a negative pressure inside the building envelope.  Venting the intake port "outside" in such a case would just be pointless.